# Database name in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query to compare the lenght of the database name in where clause.
For example if the database is named 'test1' the query must return all users with id '1234' but doesn't work.

Somebody knows how to do? This is the query:

```
select * from users where id='1234’ AND 5=(select length(database()))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "length of the database name" exactly?

Comment: *all users* with id = '1234' ??? Shouldn't the id not something ... well ... unique?

Comment: Sorry my english is very bad. Of course id is a primary key.

About the length of the database name i mean that if i have a database called 'test1' the lenght of the name is 5

Comment: How many databases would a single user be in?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfect:

```
select * from users where id='1234' AND 10=(select length(database()));
```

See this [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7100/1). The database name is `db_2_b7100`.

Comment: This problem was driving me crazy and my mistake was that all time, probabily for the layout of this keyboard, i was using the wrong apostrophe. Thanks